# IIS C# Rewriter

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

I have just started looking at URL the Rewriter module in IIS.

The code below is what I have that works (It removes www from all the URLs to the site)

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Remove WWW" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="*" />
   <conditions>
      <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="*://www.*" />       
   </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}://{C:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

However, we have a third party API that posts to http://www.example.com/api/controller/method that no longer works. (It is being served 405's)

The problem is (I believe) that whilst WebAPI allows www.example.com/api/controller/method to POST, it is seeing example.com/api/controller/method as a different URL and is not allowing POST.

However the followingconfig section does not work. (Note, removing the wildcard section means it does work, so I am as convinced as I can be that it is this that is causing the 3rd Party to fail). Though testing the PassAPICall in IIS in the configure rewriting section passes. Is it that I have misunderstood the intent of stopProcessing, and in fact all it does is stop processing for that rule, so it then falls throug hto the following condition?

```
<rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="PassAPICall" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="/api/Blah/QuotationComplete" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>

 <rule name="Remove WWW" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="*://www.*" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}://{C:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>

</rules>
```

Comment: "However the followingconfig section does not work. (Note, removing the wildcard section means it does work" What exactly does not work here?

Comment: Sorry, was at the end of a 12 hour day. Removing Rule WWW meant that the 3rd party service worked, so I was sure that was the culprit. The answer turned out to be simple this morning when I had fresh eyes. Wrapping the PassAPICall url matcher in ^ and $ fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Was a simple syntax issue, I needed to be a little more explicit with the Rule than the IIS test tool led me to believe.

changing

```
 <match url="/api/Blah/QuotationComplete" />
```

to

```
  <match url="^api/Blah/QuotationComplete$" />
```

did it.